# When setting up a new Salesforce instance for an organisation, what are the default Salesforce settings that you always change and why?

Tags: setup, defaults

I would like this to be a community wiki question.

When setting up a new Salesforce instance for an organisation, what are the settings, fields, etc that you always change, and why do you change it? (eg The terminology is too American).

Please add in any qualifiers (eg only if the organisation is a Consulting company).

I would like to limit this to default settings and not apps that you install, as that needs to be a separate question.

Please edit the answer to add your contribution.

Answer (score 5):

**Accounts**

- Change the name to **Organisations** because it allows way more
  flexibility than Accounts. Accounts has the connotation of an account
  that an advertising agency deals with (eg Mad Men style).
  Organisations allows for Suppliers, Clients, Competitors, Authorities
  etc to be added,
- Add Record Types to Accounts to allow for different fields to be added for different Org Types (as above).
- Remove the standard list of **Industry** values and add ones that are relevant to the organsiation.
- Remove the standard list of **Type** values and add ones that are relevant to the organisation.
- Rename **Billing Address** to Mailing Address and **Shipping Address** to Physical Address because who uses shipping except for orgs who sell widgets.
- Rename **SIC Code** to ABN (AUS only).
- Rename **Account Site** to Office because that makes more sense to most orgs.
- Hide **Number of Employees** and **Annual Revenue** because most orgs don't use that (or show it only on particular Record Types
- Hide Hoovers Link and add a link to ABR lookup (AUS only).

**Contacts**

- Hide **Birthdate** or add it only to particular Record Types (it seems a very American thing to track people's full Birthdates. Add fields for birth day and month is really needed.
- Rename **Title** to Position to not confuse it with Mr, Mrs etc.
- Hide **Asssistant** and **Assistant Phone** because if they are that important they should be separate contacts, and who really has assistants these days?

**UX**

- Change the company logo in the top left.
- Enable the Enhanced Inline Editing
- Enable Enhanced Lists
- Enable Spell Checker
- Enable Enhanced Profile List Views
- Enable Enhanced Profile User Interface

**Company Profile**

- Set Company Information
- Set a domain under Company Profile -> My Domain
- [Org Sandboxes] Append sandbox name to the Organization Name value

  ** Messages sent from the sandbox can then be immediately identified for a specific source without referencing an orgID. (i.e. "Sandbox: Developer script exception from MyOrg (sandbox name) : Event : Attempt to de-reference a null object")

TBC...

Answer (score 2):

Old Features:

- Remove Mail Merge from all Activity related lists (Leads, Contacts, Accounts, Opportunities)

  - Remove Request Update from all Activity related lists (Leads, Contacts, Accounts, Opportunities)
  - Remove "Last Stay In Touch.." fields from Contact

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, Jason. Since this question was meant to be a community wiki I think your answer might be better incorporated into the primary answer.